# Symfony/Doctrine - Denormalize UPDATE with relations

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I am using the Symfony serializer to denormalize JSON data and create an entity with relations.

For example:

```
$data = [
   'first' => 'John',
   'last' => 'Smith',
   'addresses' => [
       [
          'street' => 'Street',
          'city' => 'City',
          'state' => 'State'
       ]
   ]
];

$person = $this->serializer->denormalize($data, Person::class);
```

This works GREAT. However, when I need to *update* person, I am sending the same data, with the `object_to_populate` flag set:

```
$data = [
   'first' => 'John',
   'last' => 'Smith',
   'addresses' => [
       [
          'street' => 'Street',
          'city' => 'City',
          'state' => 'State'
       ]
   ]
];

$entity = $this->serializer->denormalize($data, Person::class, ['object_to_populate' => $person]);
```

This causes a duplicate key error (I have a unique key set for street+city+state). How can I have Doctrine UPDATE the relations as well, instead of trying to insert new relations?

Comment: Isn't it becase the address entity's id is null and doctrine tries to create a new one ?

Comment: I am providing the @Id fields (composite fields) of the relation in the data. That is not helping.

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#deserializing-in-an-existing-object  Did you try with  'DEEP_OBJECT_TO_POPULATE' option ?

Answer (score 0):

There exists a bundle to make your life easier. It is called [JMSSerializerBundle](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSSerializerBundle). It handle Doctrine relations out of the box.

Comment: I know. But you need now to implement some functionality it doesn't have. One way — to make it yourself and waste your time. Second way — use popular solution for it. I prefer second way. It doesn't make me waste my time. So cost of product I make decreases but quality is the same or even better